Workflow that selectively publishes artifacts based on labels
I want to publish Maven artifacts to GitHub Packages but I have more than one module in my repository and at a time not all of them will have any publishable changes. I find using labels to be pretty easy, so I used the following workflow when I had only one artifact to be published and it works fine:
name: Continuous Deployment

run-name: Deploying to GitHub Packages

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: main
    types: closed

jobs:

  deploy:

    if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged && contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'version') }}

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:

      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup the JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '21'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: maven
      
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Packages
        run: mvn -B deploy -DskipTests -f path/to/pom.xml
        env:
          PUSH_TO_PACKAGES: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

I think there is no need for multiple jobs as the only thing that needs to change here is the location of the pom file based on the label. I am thinking of having a separate label for each artifact and based on the label, the respective pom path will be chosen.
I experimented by putting the if conditions into env variables in the workflow but I couldn't get it working. I also read that switch cases don't exist in GitHub Actions (don't know for sure). I want to have a sort of nested if where:
if (IS_PR_MERGED && IS_LABELED_VERSION)
{
    if(IS_LABELED_ARTIFACT_1)
    {
        run: mvn -B deploy -DskipTests module-1/pom.xml
    }
    if(IS_LABELED_ARTIFACT_2)
    {
       run: mvn -B deploy -DskipTests module-2/pom.xml
    }
}


Another alternative could be using a setup job with the changed-files action to identify which folder has been updated automatically, and then use a matrix strategy in a further job to deploy the package for each updated folder. I've done something similar in this example (using a reusable workflow and the dorny/paths-filter action).

(I suggested this alternative as maintaining labels and workflow files may be worst than just maintaining the workflow file when new pom files may be added to the project)
